# Maven get directory name

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

On mvn install, a directory get created in target whose name contains buildnumber/timestamp.
Now I run mvn assembler where I need to use the same directory. I can not recreate the name since timestamp would change.
How can I retrieve the file name? I know the location of the file in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Bind maven-assemlby-plugin into the build life-cycle and let it run with the usual build and you have your information available during the assembly creation.